# MongoDB Compass - Stuck at connection loading

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

[mongo db stuck at connection loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWZJm.jpg)

Mongodb Compass stuck at loading connection forever. I setup the cluster from the atlas, have a database user already, and had already set my network access to 0.0.0.0/0. Have already tried searching for fixes but to no avail. Has anyone encountered this issue before? If yes, how did you solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

OK I've figured it out.

Turns out it was a DNS problem ugh.

I simply changed my DNS to 8.8.8.8

https://www.davescomputers.com/how-to-change-dns-server-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was due to Compass running on a previous network configuration. I had to reconfigure my wifi on Ubuntu to stop using  802.11n by default.

I solved my issue by reloading Compass under "View" on the toolbar:

[image: Restart option in toolbar]